# Can't insert new item into SQFlite table in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

I'm trying to create a new item in the already created table in the sqflite package in Flutter. I pass the data from the screen into a new object and when I try to create it I get and error `Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer) sql 'INSERT INTO FavouriteMovies`. Here is the code below:

SQFlite service:

```
/// creating 2 tables in one db
initDB() async {
    print('init db');

    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'movies.db');

    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {},
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute('CREATE TABLE PopularMovies('
          'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
          'title TEXT,'
          'overview TEXT,'
          'vote_average REAL,'
          'poster_path TEXT,'
          'genre_ids BLOB'
          ')');
      await db.execute('CREATE TABLE FavouriteMovies('
          'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
          'title TEXT,'
          'overview TEXT,'
          'vote_average REAL,'
          'poster_path TEXT,'
          'genre_ids BLOB'
          ')');
    });
  }

/// adding a new item to the second table

createFavouriteMovie(FavouriteMovies newMovie) async {
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db?.insert(
      'FavouriteMovies',
      newMovie.toJson(),
    );

    return res;
  }
```

Model of the data:

```
class FavouriteMovies {
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? overview;
  List<dynamic>? genreIds;
  dynamic voteAverage;
  String? posterPath;

  FavouriteMovies({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.overview,
    this.genreIds,
    this.voteAverage,
    this.posterPath,
  });

  FavouriteMovies.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    overview = json['overview'];
    genreIds = json['genre_ids'].toList();
    voteAverage = json['vote_average'];
    posterPath = json['poster_path'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = id;
    data['title'] = title;
    data['overview'] = overview;
    data['vote_average'] = voteAverage;
    data['genre_ids'] = genreIds;
    data['poster_path'] = posterPath;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Calling the create createFavouriteMovie method inside the sqflite service:

```
/// data that is passed from the previous screen
final newFavourite = FavouriteMovies(
        id: movieId,
        title: title,
        overview: description,
        voteAverage: voteAverage,
        posterPath: posterPath,
        genreIds: genres);

///calling the service
return InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              DBProvider.db.createFavouriteMovie(newFavourite);
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 45.0),
                              child: Icon(
                                toggle.contains(index)
                                    ? Icons.bookmark_added_rounded
                                    : Icons.bookmark_border_outlined,
                                size: 18,
                                color: toggle.contains(index)
                                    ? Color(0xFFEC9B3E)
                                    : Color(0xFFE4ECEF),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

I'm I parsing the data wrong? Any from of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May be your database is not created.becouse you have done many mistakes in your code first you have to close the quates and the put comma.Just copy this code and paste it in your project to create table.

```
initDB() async {

print('init db');

Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'movies.db');

return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {},
    onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
  await db.execute('''CREATE TABLE PopularMovies(
      'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
      'title TEXT',
      'overview TEXT',
      'vote_average REAL',
      'poster_path TEXT',
      'genre_ids BLOB'
      )''');
  await db.execute('''CREATE TABLE FavouriteMovies(
      'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY',
      'title TEXT',
      'overview TEXT',
      'vote_average REAL',
      'poster_path TEXT',
      'genre_ids BLOB'
      )''');
});}
```